# Laravel eloquent relation query

Tags: php, laravel

I want to retrieve the users risk categories

**risks table**

```
id
risk
category_id
```

**risk_user table**

```
id
risk_id
user_id
```

**risk_categorys**

```
id
category
```

To retrieve a risks category works fine, in my model I do this:

```
class Risk extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'risks';

    public $timestamps = false;

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    public function category() 
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('RiskCategory');
    }

}
```

But I struggle when it comes to retrieving all of the risk categories for a specific user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

**User Model**

```
class User extends Eloquent{    
    public function risks(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('Risk');
    }
}
```

Then you can use [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) to get the category for all your risks.

**Query**

```
User::find(1)->risks()->with('category')->get();
```

Since I don't have all your code nor your database I can't test it, but theoretically it should work ;) if not, just leave me a comment.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me all the risks category. However is there a simple way of getting a category only once, so the category is not repeated if same category is used on many risks?

Comment: @Bullfinch Hmm I don't think Eloquent has something built in for that. However you could either use the Query Builder or filter it in a simple PHP loop. Tell me if you need more help and I'll update my answer..

Comment: Ok, i will do it php-style then :) Thank you for your inputs.